# how should I chain function call in coffeescript

Tags: coffeescript

This coffeecode

```
obj
  .func1()
  .func2()
```

will result in

```
obj.func1().func2();
```

this work find.

But when I type this

```
obj
  .func1 "aaa"
  .func2 "bbb"
```

it will result in

```
obj.func1("aaa".func2("bbb"));
```

I must type like this

```
obj
  .func1('aaa')
  .func2('bbb')
```

that result in javsscript

```
obj.func1('aaa').func2('bbb');
```

Is there a way to omit parentthese when chain function in coffeescript?

Comment: You better discuss it as a feature request at https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues

Answer (score 19):

This issue has just been fixed [here](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1407).

So, for e.g.:

```
obj
 .func1 "aaa"
 .func2 "bbb"
```

will be compiled to

```
obj.func1("aaa").func2("bbb");
```

You may need to use the latest version at master branch for now, in npm:

```
npm install -g http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/tarball/master
```

Answer (score 9):

No way for now. There are ongoing discussions for enabling it:

- https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1407
- https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1495