# How to connect two functions for one selector in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have this coffeescript markup:

```
  body = $('body')
  body -> this.css 'background-color':'black' .addClass ('some_class')
```

how to cennect this two functions for one selector which is `body` to get this:

```
 $('body').css('background-color': 'black').addClass('some_class');
```

Comment: That's invalid jQuery usage and a JavaScript syntax error?

Comment: Well to get that output just use [this coffeescript code](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%24('body')%20-%3E%20this.css%20'background-color'%3A'black'%20.addClass%20('some_class'))

Comment: but this is wrong code...

Comment: Yes, your expected output is wrong code. What did you expect it to do? What does that object-literal-like thing mean, and why did you invoke a jQuery collection?

Comment: i just want to use this jquery methods for one selector which is body

Comment: You mean just `$('body').css('background-color':'black').addClass('some_class')`? Don't use `this` and function syntax then

Comment: sorry pasted the wrong code, now it is properly

Comment: like that   `$('body') -> css('background-color':'black') addClass('some_class');`

Comment: Again, what is that `->` supposed to do there? You've got no function in your expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use

```
$('body')
 .css('background-color':'black')
 .addClass 'some_class'
```

to get `$('body').css({
  'background-color': 'black'
}).addClass('some_class');` back. [Unfortunately CoffeeScript does not support method chaining with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10204281/1048572) without brackets.